# query to replace text with sequential numbers

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, phpmyadmin

I have an images database, the default sort is the "name" column, and the "description" column content is the exact same in all files in the table.  what I need is to replace certain text in the "description" with numbers respectively.

Example of the "description" entry to all items:

```
"Photo number # more text text"
```

The query should replace the `"#"` symbol with sequential numbers, ordered by 'name' column.  Where the first row should be `Photo number 1`, and second `Photo number 2`.. etc.

I tried some queries with row_number (in phpmyadmin), but I am not sure if it is the right way to do that or what..  as they didn't work.

Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to get an auto-incremented value and update `description` using this value. Or use [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james)'s answer and add a sequenced column to your table as a number for each picture.

```
create table t (name varchar(10), description varchar(100));
insert into t values ('b', '"Photo number # - Gallery name"');
insert into t values ('c', '"Photo number # - Gallery name"');
insert into t values ('a', '"Photo number # - Gallery name"');
insert into t values ('x', '"Photo number # - Gallery name"');
```

```
update t
join (select 
          name, @num := @num + 1 as num
      from
          t, (select @num := 0) t
      order by
          name) t2
on t2.name = t.name
set description = replace(description, '#', cast(num as varchar(10)));
```

```
select * from t order by name;
```

```
name | description                    
:--- | :------------------------------
a    | "Photo number 1 - Gallery name"
b    | "Photo number 2 - Gallery name"
c    | "Photo number 3 - Gallery name"
x    | "Photo number 4 - Gallery name"
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=39e22a8ce0686547b414d8d91f356266)*

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    photo_num INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    gallery_name VARCHAR(155),
    PRIMARY KEY(photo_num)
);
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO foo (gallery_name)
    SELECT gallery_name FROM elsewhere
        ORDER BY gallery_name;
```